# How to get date columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I need a separate date column(in this format2018-10-08) in this table. please help.

```
   id   id2     post    id  level   created_at
0   150     126293  BA     237602   0   2018-10-08 15:37:06.404741
1   150     126293  BA     217350   0   2018-09-26 11:27:20.610651
2   4655    169068  BA     172174   1   2018-08-07 15:54:15.961607
3   14058   201462  BA      231703  1   2018-10-04 18:26:06.915134
4   16576   241053  agent   416451  2   2019-02-06 16:59:41.550580
5   16576   241053  agent   423247  2   2019-02-10 18:10:12.987203
6   16700   102938  BA     476606   0   2019-03-07 23:23:36.902590
7   50374   131808  TSM     203392  0   2018-09-13 21:54:45.874108
8   50374   131808  TSM     103873  0   2018-03-23 17:30:20.647447
```

Comment: You may read documentation before asking. [date handling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [column selection](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: Did you mean to get only the date (2018-10-08) and remove the time?

Answer (score 1):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']).dt.date
```

[to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html): Convert argument to datetime. For example, if your column of "created_at" is a string column, it converts it to a datetime column

[dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html): Access object for datetime like properties of the Series values.

Comment: This is probably the best (code) answer so far, but you should probably include some words e.g explaining why first using `pd.to_datetime` is necessary and what `.dt.` is. Links to documentation are also a good idea :)

Comment: Now it is a complete answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the following code:

```
date = df['created_at']
df.drop('created_at', inlace = True)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation of what your code does. Ultimately, the output of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  df['date'] = df['created_at'].str.extract('(....-..-..)', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `created_at` column is of the `datetime` type, you can use the [.dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) method to only get the date as follows:

```
df["date_column"] = df["created_at"].dt.date
```

This will return the following column:

```
date_column
2018-10-08
2018-09-26
2018-08-07
2018-10-04
2019-02-06
2019-02-10
2019-03-07
2018-09-13
2018-03-23
```